# Query syntax error on HQL Query

Tags: hql

**Hql query:**

```
Select ecd.consumption from com.dventus.wonchi.jaxb.messages.Wonchi as w 
join w.systemBound as consumption 
join consumption.fixedNetwork as ecd 
where w.meterId = 'DVEHighLowUsageCheck' and ecd.time in (select min(ecd.time))
```

**Exception**:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected end of subtree [Select ecd.consumption from com.dventus.wonchi.jaxb.messages.Wonchi as w join w.systemBound as consumption join consumption.fixedNetwork as ecd where w.meterId = 'DVEHighLowUsageCheck' and ecd.time in (select min(ecd.time))]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed for @getjackx, the syntax is incorrect.

You need add the clause `FROM` for the subselect `select min(ecd.time)`, like:

```
select min(ecd2.time) FROM FixedNetwork ec2
```

Comment: Syntax is incorrect. You need to specify a table in the subselect e.g. `select min(ecd.time) from TABLE`

Comment: @getjackx Oh yeah, I will erase this part of my answer.